# ASP.NET Dropdown always getting an empty value?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, dropdown

I have a dropdownlist populated with values I get from a SQL database. Then, I need to upload a file using the value selected from the dropdownlist, but for some reason, I always get the value of the next empty value in the list that does not currently have a file. Example:

Value A  -> File | Value B -> File | Value C -> No file | Value D -> No file

If I select value D in the dropdown, and I click the submit button, I then debug and always get Value C as the selected value, why? I don't know, because if it was for the postback I would always get the default value, in this case value A. And all other values I am getting to fill in the object are getting correctly, all but the selected value of the dropdown.

Code - frontend:

```
<asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlDocumentos" 
     runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Backend:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    proveedor = docList.GetAllbyUserIdFinal(u.Id);  //Here, I fill the dropdown

    ddlDocumentos.DataSource = proveedor;

    ddlDocumentos.DataTextField = "Descripcion";
    ddlDocumentos.DataValueField = "Nombre";

    ddlDocumentos.DataBind();

    d.Descripcion = ddlDocumentos.SelectedItem.Text; // Every time I stop here, selecteditem always gets Value C and not D, even tho I select D.
    d.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Comment: Very little we can do with the very limited information you've provided

Comment: Thing is, there isn't much more as for the dropdownlist, I am getting it, filling it and then, for some reason (I think not related to Postback), I am always getting the upper value and not really the selected one. Tried addding as much as I think will be useful, but maybe I am losing some pointers?

Comment: It's better to data-bind the dropdown only on the initial request and not on postbacks (i.e., `if (!this.IsPostBack) { ... }`).

Comment: Yeah, it is binded in the PostBack specifically :(

Comment: Again, don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Remember, if you re-bind and re-load the dropdown list, then you LOSE the existing choice!!!

This means in the vast majority of web pages that you build?

You need to place your loading code inside of the VERY important !IsPostBack stub in the page load event.

Remember, any button click, any post back? The page load event will again EACH time, and run before say a button click code stub.
So, page load event will run each time.

So, your code needs that !IsPostBack code stub in page load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        proveedor = docList.GetAllbyUserIdFinal(u.Id);  //Here, I fill the dropdown

        ddlDocumentos.DataSource = proveedor;

        ddlDocumentos.DataTextField = "Descripcion";
        ddlDocumentos.DataValueField = "Nombre";

        ddlDocumentos.DataBind();

        d.CreatedDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

So, note how we ONLY want to load up, setup the dropdown list one time. If you re-bind each time, then you will "blow out" and over-write the current selection in the dropdown list.

So, it stands to reason that to build a working asp.net webforms page?

You will 99 out of 100 times will require that all important! IsPostBack stub. As I stated, you in fact can't build a working web page without this! IsPostBack code block.

So, with !IsPostBack, then that setup code, the code to load up grids or dropdowns, or whatever? Such code can ONLY run one time, since the "act" of loading up a GridView, or a dropdown list or ANY data bound control will of course lose its existing value WHEN you re-bind the data for that given control.

And of course, the 2nd big issue here is that is makes VERY little sense on each page re-load (each post-back) that we are to re-load the controls again and again with data. Why waste all that data processing for no gains?

So, add your !IsPostBack block to the page load event, and the selected value of the dropdown will remain selected, and persist.